# How to get a gmail profile image belong to a user?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, google-authentication

I am working on one of the Django project where I have used **social_django** framework provided by the Django team for single sign-on with google, Now my requirement is to fetch the profile image related to that Gmail account

Link of documentation for single sign-on
https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html

**setting.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ....
    'social_django'
]

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'social_core.backends.open_id.OpenIdAuth',
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOpenId',
 'social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2',
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
SOCIAL_AUTH_URL_NAMESPACE = 'social'

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.debug.debug',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'social.pipeline.debug.debug',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_IGNORE_DEFAULT_SCOPE = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SCOPE = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile'
]
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required
@transaction.atomic
def update_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            messages.error(request, ('Please correct the error below.'))
    else:
        user_form = UserForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'testapp/profile.html', {
        'user_form': user_form,
        'profile_form': profile_form
    })
```

**models.py**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**form.py**

```
from django import forms
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('bio','location','birth_date')
```

**output**
When I used to log in with my Gmail account then somehow I get this data

```
{'access_token': ---,
 'email': 'xyz@gmail.com',
 'email_verified': True,
 'expires_in': 3599,
 'family_name': 'xyz',
 'given_name': 'xyz',
 'hd': 'gmail.com',
 'id_token': --- ,
 'locale': 'en',
 'name': 'xyz xyz',
 'picture': 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-qcnZYR0SC4bwr',
 'scope': ---,
 'sub': ---,
 'token_type': ---}
================================================================================
{'email': 'xyz@gmail.com',
 'first_name': 'xyz',
 'fullname': 'xyz xyz',
 'last_name': 'xyz',
 'username': 'xyz'}
================================================================================
()
================================================================================
{'backend': <social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2>,
 'is_new': False,
 'new_association': False,
 'pipeline_index': 7,
 'request': ---,
 'social': <UserSocialAuth: xyz>,
 'storage': <class 'social_django.models.DjangoStorage'>,
 'strategy': <social_django.strategy.DjangoStrategy>,
 'uid': 'xyz@gmail.com',
 'user': <User: xyz>,
 'username': 'xyz'}
```

**Question**
1) I am able to get all the information related to a user how that information is coming out that I do not understand??
2) How do I store this information to a database (user name, email address and image link)